# Is there a workaround to Chrome's Canvas bug with missing pixels using lineTo

Tags: google-chrome, canvas, html5-canvas

There is a known bug in Chrome's Canvas implementation where successive calls to lineTo will sometimes drop pixels at the corner: http://jsfiddle.net/rPJBr/2/

```
var cx = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');
cx.beginPath();
cx.moveTo(200.5, 200.5);
cx.lineTo(200.5, 100.5);
cx.lineTo(100.5, 100.5);
cx.stroke();
```

Here's an image and a zoom-in of the behavior on chrome 24 on win7

[image: missing corner pixel repro]

The bug has been logged here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137465

Is there a known workaround for this bug?

Comment: Fiddle with decimal values and use something else than 0.5 to trigger the pixel filling?

Comment: Or manually fill in corner pixels after drawing the rectangle?

Comment: The problem is more generally that if you try to fill the corner pixel, it's very hard to preserve the line-join stlye

Answer (score 0):

```
if(windows.chrome) {
    var p = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype;
    p.origLineTo = p.lineTo;
    p.lineTo = function(x, y) {
        this.fillRect(x - 0.5, y - 0.5, 1, 1);
        return this.origLineTo(x, y);
    };
    p.origMoveTo = p.moveTo;
    p.moveTo = function(x, y) {
        this.fillRect(x - 0.5, y - 0.5, 1, 1);
        return this.origMoveTo(x, y);
    };
}
```